# How to Filter Out All column = null Rows Past the Last column != null Row, by an Offset, in the Result of a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, native-sql

I have an SQL table that looks like this:

```
Flow             Head            Series_Name

0                null            A           
0                null            B
10               null            A
10               null            B
20               null            A
22.5             88              B
20               null            B
30               null            A
30               null            B
39.42            60.1            A
40               null            A
40               null            B
etc...           etc...          etc...
5000             null            A
5000             null            B
```

Basically, the idea of this table is to be able to use it to plot Flow vs Head in a Line Chart element in Cognos Report Studio. This works nicely, since I can drag and drop the Flow column into the X-Axis, the Head column into the Y-Axis, and the Series_Name column into the Legend. For the example table above, this produces two curves, A and B.

Notice that Flow values are ranging from 0 to 5000, incrementing by 10, for both series. Notice also that Head values are mostly null, except when a data point is available. (Typically, data points' Flow values don't fall exactly on numbers that are divisible by 10, but if they do, it shouldn't matter for the problem I have.)

So, here's the problem I have. When I generate the Line Chart, everything looks great, except for those assets whose data points have lower Flow values. For these, the fixed X-Axis range of 0 to 5000 doesn't produce a nice looking Line Chart, since the curve is scrunched up against the Y-Axis. (The Y-Axis, by the way, looks just fine, since the Line Chart element automatically scales its Y-Axis.)

I know what needs to happen to fix this problem. I need to be able to write an SQL query to this table that filters out all rows with Head = null past whatever the last Head != null row is. It would also be nice to have an offset so that it didn't start to cut off until a few rows past the last Head != null row. This would make the chart look even nicer.

For the example table I gave above, if you assume that the Flow = 39.42 & Head = 60.1 row is the last Head != null row in the table, then a nice query result from this table would be the following, which excludes all the rows (by an offset of 6 rows) past it:

```
Flow             Head            Series_Name 

0                null            A           
0                null            B
10               null            A
10               null            B
20               null            A
22.5             88              B
20               null            B
30               null            A
30               null            B
39.42            60.1            A
40               null            A
40               null            B
50               null            A
50               null            B
60               null            A
60               null            B
```

I know this requires a WHERE clause at the end of the SELECT statement, but I'm not sure how to phrase such a clause in order to exclude rows only if they're part of the unnecessary latter part of the query result. The SQL query needs to be written in Native SQL syntax.

This sort of query result, which cuts off all unnecessary data, would graph beautifully! I appreciate the help!

Comment: Why is this tagged with Oracle and MySQL - which DBMS does it need to run in, and which version? And what does 'native SQL' mean in this context?

Comment: I wasn't sure exactly how to tag it. Im running IBM Cognos Report Studio inside of DataStream, which is a SQL server of some sort. To provide you with more context, Im a new engineering intern at a wastewater management company so I don't know all the ins and outs of the server yet... As for "native SQL", that's just what Report Studio was calling it. I can either write queries in "native SQL" or "Cognos SQL." Very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make this example in **[SQL SERVER](http://rextester.com/RUCHL57472)** same code should work in oracle

```
SELECT *
from Events
WHERE Flow <= (SELECT max(Flow) + 3*10 FROM Events WHERE [HEAD] IS NOT NULL)
```

> 3*10 to offset three more rows.

If you want something more generic and scalable you can use `row_number()` but need to be carefull with the `order by`

```
WITH addRow_id as (
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [Flow], [Series_Name]) as rn
     FROM Events
),
lastID as (
     SELECT MAX(rn) as last_row
     FROM addRow_id
     WHERE [HEAD] IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM addRow_id A
CROSS JOIN lastID L
WHERE A.rn <= L.last_row + 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly get everything below the cut off, and union that to everything above the cutoff but ordered by the flow with a limit of 10 applied:-

```
SELECT *
FROM sometable
WHERE flow <= 
(
    SELECT MAX(flow)
    FROM sometable 
    WHERE head IS NOT NULL
)
UNION
SELECT flow, head, series_name
FROM
(
    SELECT flow, head, series_name
    FROM sometable
    WHERE flow > 
    (
        SELECT MAX(flow)
        FROM sometable 
        WHERE head IS NOT NULL
    )
    ORDER BY flow
    LIMIT 10
) sub1
```

But depends on the details of the order